# How to setup local Kafka to validate schema?

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I read that schema validation is available in Kafka Confluent Server only. But maybe since then someone has found a solution? Does anyone know how can I test message validity running Kafka locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to enforce broker to validate producers' input

Kafka doesn't do this. **Confluent Server** can, yes, but it is enterprise licensed. There is no alternative to server-side validation without forking Kafka like Confluent did. Otherwise, you would need to write your own Serializer class, but that won't scale to every producer client you may use.

You can still use Docker as the other answer shows, and you can use `confluentinc/cp-server` image, then you simply add an environment variable to enable schema valdiation.

https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/schema-validation.html

Otherwise, simply using JsonSchemaSerializer, for example, will validate each record **does** adhere to a schema (client-side validation), but it won't stop anyone else from sending garbage data into the topic (server-side validation).

Comment: > but that won't scale to every producer client you may use
Can you please explain it a bit?

Comment: Imagine you're in a large company with thousands of developers. You write your own serializer to do some custom validation logic for your topic. Some other team/developers also wants to send data to your topic. They don't about your validator, only the topic contains some data they want to use... Nothing forces anyone to copy your validating code, and it will need to be, which won't scale

Comment: Can I write custom serialiser for broker?

Comment: Nope. Serializers are only properties for producers. Kafka broker only accepts bytes, which have no schema themselves. I am not aware of any way to intercept the bytes that the broker receives. Without forking Kafka, you would need a TCP Proxy to intercept client request-responses, then run that as-if it were a "fake Kafka broker".